# Blazor page what is the best way to get data based on various filtered conditions from the server's controller?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, repository-pattern

We have a Blazor WASM project on .NET 7, using VS 2022, C#, SQL Server, and a repository pattern.

We have a Blazor page that allows the client user to select filters to fill an HTML table of filtered data from the server-side database repository. We anticipate when placed into production there can be a million rows in a SQL Server view for the page.

My question is asking the best way to implement the `GET` data request on the server side.

I see the request starting at the PAGE calling the client service that invokes the server controller that fetches data from the server repository.

For example, getting data from the SQL Server view that can contain a million rows, and I am wondering the best way to fetch the filtered data.

I see the service function and controller method supporting parameters that can be used in a LINQ statement that can use

```
somecollection.Where(...field1==value1 && field2==value2...etc.)
```

from a collection of `GetAllRecords()` call from the repository.

Is this a good way to return back to the client-side the list of filtered data of 100 rows (for example)?

From my limited knowledge and perspective, I ask...

- should the controller do the filtering by a Linq statement

OR

- should the repository perform the Linq filtering

OR

- have a number of SQL Server stored procedures called by the repository

OR

- some other manner

Comment: Ideally avoid bringing the data back from the database if you don't need it. Beyond that just follow your design practices.

Comment: Thank you Dale.  The flow of "data" from the database occurs, I think, in the repository code on the server.  The controller is also on the server.  So, I surmise that we should NOT bring 1-million records from the repository (DB) to the controller and LINQ-filter from there to return 100 filtered records back to the client. It appears that SQL-stored procedures should allow for the filtering to return only 100-records to the repository and then to the controller and finally to the client for display. Comments?  thx

Answer (score 0):

Based on the helpful comments, I found it easy to create a stored procedure with parameters so that the DB fetches only 100-records back to the controller and to the client service.
I am/was very familiar with stored procedures from my VB and ASP experience but did not know I could call the SProc from the repository. A few searches brought me to the C# code I used to remedy my original question.  Here is the link...

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pchandraker/passing-table-valued-parameter-to-stored-procedu-part-1/